# Парсинг данных после авторизации на сайте

Tags: python, парсер

Имеется сайт, для простоты это будет вк. Необходимо запарсить данные на этом сайте, но доступ к ним можно получить только после авторизации через логин/пароль, api никаких нет, причём страница с авторизацией имеет условный домен test.com/login, а после успешного входа перебрасывает на страницу test.com/my. Каким образом можно запарсить данные (логин и пароль естественно имеются). Буду благодарен за литературную наводку

Answer (score 0):

На большинстве сайтов, авторизация считается пройденной если в файлах cookie есть нужная строка. Следовательно, нужно отправить методом POST логин и пароль на сайт, получить отправленную сайтом cookie, при следующих запросах отправлять полученую cookie. Всё решаемо при помощи стандартной библиотеки, но говорят что urllib3, requests лучше. *- это инструкция для стандартной автризации, есть ещё несколько разновидностей, которые используются, но редко